# How to delete item from RecyclerView and database?

Tags: java, android, database

Adding and removing items from RecyclerView is working, but i don't know if i have written a good method in database for deleting rows because only i'm saving condition when item is added and when it is removed and if i leave from app and come back, but previosly i have deleted some items, i'm seeing them there. So i need some help about this method in database for removing items and also implementing it in activity.

Here are my code:

**DATABASE:**

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "items.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";

    private final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private final String COLUMN_ITEM = "item";

    private static DBHelper dbh;

    private DBHelper(Activity activity) {
        super(activity, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static synchronized DBHelper getConnection(Activity activity) {
        if (dbh == null)
            dbh = new DBHelper(activity);
        return dbh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String upitZaPravljanjeBaze =
                "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_ITEMS+"("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+COLUMN_ITEM+" TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(upitZaPravljanjeBaze);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE" + "TABLE_ITEMS");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllItems() {
        ArrayList<String> toRet = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            toRet.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEM)));
            c.moveToNext();

        }

        return toRet;
    }

    public long saveItem(String item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_ITEM, item);
        return db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, cv);
    }

    public boolean deleteItem(long rowId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_ITEMS, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

}
```

**ADAPTER:**

```
    public class AdapterRecyclerAnimators extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecyclerAnimators.Holder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mListData = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;


    public AdapterRecyclerAnimators(Context context) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_item, parent, false);
        Holder holder = new Holder(row);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, final int position) {
        String data = mListData.get(position);
        holder.textDataItem.setText(data);
        holder.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public void addItem(String item) {
        mListData.add(item);
        notifyItemInserted(mListData.size());
    }
    public void addAll(ArrayList<String> newList){
        mListData = newList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeItem(String item) {
        int position = mListData.indexOf(item);
        if (position != -1) {
            mListData.remove(item);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mListData.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListData.size();
    }

    public static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textDataItem;
        ImageButton buttonDelete;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textDataItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_item);
            buttonDelete = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);

        }
    }

}
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    //int containing the duration of the animation run when items are added or removed from the RecyclerView
    public static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 2000;
    //edit text letting the user type item name to be added to the recylcerview
    private EditText mInput;
    //itemcounter for recyclerview
    private TextView mItemCounter;
    //recyclerview showing all items added by the user
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private AdapterRecyclerAnimators mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> mListData = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initViews();

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            ArrayList<String> items = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("items");
            mListData.addAll(items);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putStringArrayList("items", mListData);
    }

    private void initViews(){
        mInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_input);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerAnimatedItems);
        mItemCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemCounter);
        mItemCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mRecyclerView.getChildCount()));
        mAdapter = new AdapterRecyclerAnimators(this);
        //set an animator on the RecyclerView that works only when items are added or removed
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInLeftAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setAddDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setRemoveDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mAdapter.addAll(DBHelper.getConnection(MainActivity.this).getAllItems());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    public void addItem(View view) {
        //check if the EditText has valid contents
        if (Util.hasValidContents(mInput)) {
            DBHelper.getConnection(MainActivity.this)
                    .saveItem(mInput.getText().toString());

            ArrayList<String> allItems = DBHelper.getConnection(MainActivity.this).getAllItems();

            mAdapter.addAll(allItems);

            mInput.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are your delete methode:

```
public void removeItem(String item) {
    int position = mListData.indexOf(item);
    if (position != -1) {
        mListData.remove(item);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    mListData.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

You remove the items from your list but you never remove them from your database. Call your delete method in both of of these methods and see if it works.

Comment: That part i don't understand. How to call that method in these delete methods?

Comment: In the same way you  call the mothods to add items to your database

Comment: But it's not the same. I'm adding them in activity and in this case i need to add them to adapter. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't necessarily think this will fix your problem but thought I would point it out, In your database delete method you have:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
```

You probably want to switch that:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```